# acquireTokenAsync method throwing error if userId is not passed

Tags: azure, cordova, adal, azure-ad-graph-api, intune

I'm using the [Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) library for Apache Cordova](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova) on an **Ionic** mobile application. I'm running into an issue calling **acquireTokenAsync**

Note: **I'm using Microsoft Intune and I've enabled broker Authentication**

[image]

The generated token from the acquireTokenAsync call "appears" to be valid, but when I run a post (post is happening in my express middleware) to **https://login.microsoftonline.com/**********/oauth2/token**, I get the error message below. As you can see in the signature of the calls in the above image, the userId ***should*** be optional.

[image]

*Anyone have any ideas why this is happening when I avoid using the userId **optional** parameter? I don't get this error message if I include the userId*

Here is the **configuration object** I use in the post to the **/oauth2/token endpoint**.

```
            grant_type: 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            client_id: ********,
            client_secret:*******
            assertion: ******
            requested_token_use: 'on_behalf_of',
            resource: ‘https://graph.microsoft.com/’,
            scope: 'openid email offline_access User.Read Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared'
```

Here is my environment configuration 
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.9
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
Node              : v8.11.1
npm               : 5.6.0 
OS                : macOS High Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.3 Build version 9E145
```

Comment: Hang on, are you using a client secret from within a native app?

Comment: juunas, that secret is part of the configuration options sent to the post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/**********/oauth2/token inside an express node.js api.

Comment: That error might be related to Conditional Access, are you using it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-device-remediation

Comment: Since the error sounds like you have a policy that blocks devices which are not AAD-joined

Comment: @juunas thanks for the tips. We are using intune. From what I understand we don't manage or have a policy for AAD joined devices.

Comment: @juunas, what is strange is the error does not appear and works if I provide the userId

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue is not associated with the userId. The cordova library is referencing an older version of the native libraries and does not include a recent release that would fix this issue.